# Ubuntu 12.04 despite the left panel POLI tray present, myunity says that unity turns in 2d

Tags: unity, 12.04, 3d, opengl, myunity

How do I enable unity 3d?
I state that I have used the correct login to ubuntu to ubuntu and not 2d
below the glxinfo

```
stefano@WorkLinux:~$ glxinfo | grep render
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 55
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 56
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 59
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 58
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NV34
```

Comment: Stef, can you convert to English? This is an English site. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the correct installation of the video driver, otherwise try this:

If you use GNOME Classic APPLICATIONS> SYSTEM TOOLS> START OF APPLICATIONS

If you use GNOME Shell or Unity write APPLICATIONS FOR INITIATING in research programs

Will open a window, click Add, and under COMMAND type: compiz - replace

Then you or END SESSION or reboot your computer and see if it works.